# Remove all special characters except for @ symbol from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a **string**:

```
“Gazelles were mentioned by @JohnSmith while he had $100 in his pocket and screamed W#$@%@$!!!!"
```

I need:

```
“Gazelles were mentioned by @JohnSmith while he had 100 in his pocket and screamed"
```

How to remove all special characters from string EXCEPT the @ symbol. I tried:

```
str.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
```

Comment: Add an @ to the character class `[^\w\s@]`

Comment: Thank you. I also have sentences with the ↵ symbol, which isn't getting removed.

Comment: Do you want to keep the `@` only when it is followed by a word char? `(?:[^\w\s@]+|@(?!\w))`

Comment: That would be ideal.

Comment: The `W` at the end, is that supposed to be gone or not?

Comment: That can stay. Just special characters including ↵ symbol , but keep the @

Comment: So I'd go with: `@(?!\w)|[^\w\s@]` for example. Pretty much what @TheFourthBird mentioned earlier.

Comment: ↵ symbol still there. Not sure why

Comment: Got the symbol with replace(/\n/ig, ''). Works now, thanks! Add answer if you want points.

Comment: Can you show the string where that actually is still remained in place? [This](https://regex101.com/r/09trlp/1) for example worked fine.

Comment: That is because the `\s` in the negated character class makes it not match a newline. It could be like this for example `[^\w \t@]+|@(?!\w)` https://regex101.com/r/2fM0LK/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the `@` when it is followed by a word char and keeping the `W` is also ok and also remove the newlines, you could for example change the `\s` to match spaces or tabs `[ \t]`

Add the `@` to the negated character class and use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) specifying to only match the `@` when it is not followed by a word character using a negative lookahead.

```
[^\w \t@]+|@(?!\w)
```

- `[^\w \t@]+` Match 1+ times any char except a word char, space or tab
- `|` Or
- `@(?!\w)` Match an @ not directly followed by a word char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2fM0LK/1)

In the replacement use an empty string.